# aiohttp: multiple requests to same URL return authentication error, but the URL is correct

Tags: python, python-asyncio, aiohttp, strava

I am using the below code to make 599 asynchronous requests to Strava API.
For some reason the response I get for each of them is

> {"message":"Authorization
>   Error","errors":[{"resource":"Application","field":"","code":"invalid"}]}

This is the type of error you typically get when your `access_token` query string parameter
is invalid.
But in this case the token is 100% correct: the URL returns correct response when just
copy-pasted manually in the browser.

What might be the reason of the error and how to fix it? Might it be that the `aiohttp` session is somehow
messing the authentication procedure up?

Note: for privacy reasons the token in the code below is fake.

```
import aiohttp
import asyncio

async def fetch(session, url):
    async with session.get(url) as response:
        print(await response.text())

async def main():
    urls = ['''https://www.strava.com/api/v3/activities/
            280816027?include_all_efforts=true&
            access_token=11111111'''] * 599
    async with aiohttp.ClientSession() as session:
        tasks = [
                    asyncio.ensure_future(fetch(session, url))
                    for url in urls
        ]
        await asyncio.gather(*tasks)

loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
loop.run_until_complete(main())
```

Comment: Did you try to configure `aiohttp` to produce debugging output? What output did you get? It should show the exact HTTP requests that it is sending...

Comment: You shouldn't use a multiline string as the URL, because it will keep all whitespaces and as a result you will get the wrong URL

Comment: Thanks @Artemiy, that did the trick! Please post an answer, so I can accept.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't use a multiline string as the URL, because it will keep all whitespaces and as a result you will get the wrong URL.